# Наследование конкретного конструктора | C++

Tags: c++, наследование, using

Можно ли унаследовать конкретный конструктор при помощи using декларации? Мы можем сделать следующее при наследовании:

```
using myclass::myclass;
```

Но в таком случае будут наследованы все конструкторы, можно ли, например, унаследовать только конструктор копирования или для этого придется явно написать каждый в наследуемом классе?

Comment: похоже, что такого синтаксиса нет

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет, унаследовать конкретные конструкторы с помощью using-декларации невозможно: [[namespace.udecl]](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/n4868.pdf#section.9.9) не описывает такого синтаксиса. Лишь все вместе.

Если вам нужно унаследовать лишь конкретные конструкторы - вам придется написать каждый требуемый вам конструктор и в нем произвести вызов конструктора базового класса, пользуясь *[делегирующим конструктором](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/delegating-constructors?view=msvc-160)*.